# Percona pt-table-checksum output is in infinite loop "Waiting for the --replicate table to replicate"

Tags: mariadb, percona, pt-table-checksum

We have following Multi master replication scenario. We are using Mariadb 10.1.34 and percona 3.0.11

- Master:  Name: db-master1 (192.168.14.5)
- Slave:   Name: db-slave2 (192.168.15.5) Replica Connection name:
  master1 (192.168.14.5)

`SHOW SLAVE 'master1' STATUS\G` on slave server is working fine.

On execution of following `pt-table-checksum` command on DB Master (db-master1)

```
pt-table-checksum --replicate=percona.checksums --ignore-databases mysql,Quotient h=localhost,u=checksum_user,p=checksum_password --recursion-method=dsn=D=percona,t=dsns  --no-check-binlog-format
Checking if all tables can be checksummed ...
Starting checksum ...
Replica db-slave2 is stopped.  Waiting.
Replica db-slave2 is stopped.  Waiting.
```

On Master1-db, the percona.dsns table have entry for db-slave2

The Above Waiting information is continue in infinite loop.

Look forward any support

Answer (score 0):

On Master DB Server

(i) For safe side, I made copy of original /bin/pt-table-checksum

cp /bin/pt-table-checksum /bin/pt-table-checksumorg

(ii) Open the /bin/pt-table-checksum file

vi /bin/pt-table-checksum

(iii) Go to line number 8590
 Press esc, type 8590 , press shift g

(iv) replace the line
   my @lagged_slaves = map { {cxn=>$_, lag=>undef} } @$slaves;
by
    my @lagged_slaves = ();

the program immediately works and returns the expected results.